How to correctly extract media data from tweets (X api V2) with Tweepy 4.6?
After collecting tweets, I am unable to create a DataFrame for the media (ValueError: can not infer schema from empty dataset). I have determined that the media is not being collected correctly. There must be an issue with my collection process. I believe I have included the necessary media expansion parameters in the tweet collection request. I would like to know if my media collection is being done correctly, or if there might be another explanation for this issue?
for tweet in tweepy.Paginator(
    client.search_recent_tweets,
    query=query,
    tweet_fields=['id', 'text', 'author_id', 'created_at', 'public_metrics', 'lang', 'source', 'context_annotations', 'entities'],
    expansions=['author_id', 'attachments.media_keys', 'geo.place_id', 'entities.mentions.username', 'referenced_tweets.id'],
    user_fields=['id', 'name', 'username', 'location', 'description', 'url', 'protected', 'public_metrics', 'profile_image_url', 'verified', 'created_at'],
    media_fields=['url', 'preview_image_url', 'type'],  # Add media fields if you need information on media
    place_fields=['full_name', 'country', 'country_code'],  # Add place fields if you need information on location
    max_results=10
).flatten(limit=maxtweets_persearch):

    print(f"Tweet ID: {tweet.id}")
    print(f"Texte: {tweet.text}")
    print(f"Auteur ID: {tweet.author_id}")
    print(f"Créé à: {tweet.created_at}")
    print(f"Langue: {tweet.lang}")

#Rest of code 

        # Media processing
    if 'attachments' in tweet.data and 'media_keys' in tweet.data['attachments']:
        media_keys = tweet.data['attachments']['media_keys']
        for media_key in media_keys:
            media_object = client.get_media(media_key, media_fields=['media_key', 'type', 'url', 'duration_ms', 'height', 'width', 'preview_image_url', 'public_metrics', 'alt_text']).data
            if media_object:
                media = {
                    'id': tweet.id,
                    'media_key': media_object['media_key'],
                    'type': media_object['type'],
                    'url': media_object.get('url'),  # Use get to avoid KeyError if the URL is not available
                    'preview_image_url': media_object.get('preview_image_url'),
                    'view_count': media_object['public_metrics'].get('view_count', 0) if media_object.get('public_metrics') else 0,
                    # Add other fields if necessary
                }
                all_media.append(media)
    else:
        print("No media attached to this tweet.")

I tried printing the media after collection, but I consistently receive  as output the message 'No media attached to this tweet' .
Output :
Tweet ID: 1789426115968221644
Texte: RT @Fleechiru: Microsoft and Sony are locked in an endless war to see who can have less games
Auteur ID: 805541162916413444
Créé à: 2024-05-11 22:43:26+00:00
Langue: en
No media attached to this tweet.
Tweet ID: 1789426113640284658
Texte: RT @Fleechiru: Microsoft and Sony are locked in an endless war to see who can have less games
Auteur ID: 887727180
Créé à: 2024-05-11 22:43:26+00:00
Langue: en
No media attached to this tweet.
Tweet ID: 1789426109731234165
Texte: https:.....
Auteur ID: 1534078604279263232
Créé à: 2024-05-11 22:43:25+00:00
Langue: zxx
No media attached to this tweet.
Tweet ID: 1789426092836553015
Texte: RT @Andronews_net: Fan enojado le lanza una bomba nuclear al CEO de Microsoft gaming (Phil Spencer) en Fallout 76 luego de que anunciaran e…
Auteur ID: 1144666700064927745
Créé à: 2024-05-11 22:43:21+00:00
Langue: es
No media attached to this tweet..................etc..


ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-203-eb753417537b> in <module>
    120 
    121 
--> 122 df_media = spark.createDataFrame(Row(**x) for x in all_media)
    123 file_path = base_path + 'TweetsMediaData/' + str(query) + '_' + str(topic) + foldername_suffix
    124 df_media.write.format('json').save(file_path)

/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/session.py in createDataFrame(self, data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema)
    746             rdd, schema = self._createFromRDD(data.map(prepare), schema, samplingRatio)
    747         else:
--> 748             rdd, schema = self._createFromLocal(map(prepare, data), schema)
    749         jrdd = self._jvm.SerDeUtil.toJavaArray(rdd._to_java_object_rdd())
    750         jdf = self._jsparkSession.applySchemaToPythonRDD(jrdd.rdd(), schema.json())

/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/session.py in _createFromLocal(self, data, schema)
    414 
    415         if schema is None or isinstance(schema, (list, tuple)):
--> 416             struct = self._inferSchemaFromList(data, names=schema)
    417             converter = _create_converter(struct)
    418             data = map(converter, data)

/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/session.py in _inferSchemaFromList(self, data, names)
    341         """
    342         if not data:
--> 343             raise ValueError("can not infer schema from empty dataset")
    344         first = data[0]
    345         if type(first) is dict:

ValueError: can not infer schema from empty dataset



